# Switching an existing private RDS MySQL instance to be publicly accessible

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, rds

I have an existing RDS instance running mysql inside a VPC
It is (was all along) associated with the public subnets of the VPC
The public subnets all share one "public" route table that has a Internet Gateway (IGW) attached (they are explicitly attached to this route table)
It was not originally, but now is set to be publicly accessible
It has a Security group which allows access from outside and I tried both wide open and specific IP here.

Yet still when I attempt to connect the connection just times out ...

```
$ mysql -usomeuser -h somename.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'somename.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)
```

What am I missing? anyone ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your RDS instance is truly public:

- Is in a subnet with an internet gateway
- Using a security group that is appropriately open to the internet

Your RDS instance needs to have it's "Publicly Accessible" setting to set to Yes/True. If it is No/False, then resolving your DNS entry of `somename.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` will result in it's private IP address, which will not work from the outside world.